# Geth not syncing Ropsten - why?

Tags: go-ethereum

Geth not syncing Ropsten - why?

```
:~/Eth$ geth --testnet --syncmode fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303" console
WARN [01-30|11:00:25.885] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=1024 updated=330
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.886] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.888] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.21-stable-9dc5d1a9/linux-amd64/go1.10.4
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.888] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata cache=165 handles=524288
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.895] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.909] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=355 size=51.89kB time=3.106772ms gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.909] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Constantinople: 4230000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.910] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.910] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/ubuntu/.ethash                       count=2
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.910] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.917] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576 age=49y9mo2w
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.917] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576 age=49y9mo2w
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.917] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576 age=49y9mo2w
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.918] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.925] New local node record                    seq=1 id=27b8506d54072297 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.926] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
INFO [01-30|11:00:25.960] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://374ba74ed85d381f0088fabb0a48bcee2a28aba6173e08d8efd0bc19ded692c7f2716dab45a3ff092b419cba071dabaf9df357100d38b06b1e54d0e3830a7756@127.0.0.1:30303
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.8.21-stable-9dc5d1a9/linux-amd64/go1.10.4
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> 
> eth.syncing
false
> eth.blockNumber
0
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to open port 30303 for TCP and UDP.

Shame the log does not output that as an error - I would have thought that was possible to check.